# GSON - convert keys to lowercase

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to write a GSON TypeAdapterFactory to convert all the keys in String-type key/value pairs to lowercase; i.e. it would convert:

```
[{"Foo","Bar"}]
```

to

```
[{"foo","Bar"}]
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm having trouble with determining when the key is a String value.  The `JsonTreeWriter` class has a `name()` Setter method, but no method for Getting the name?

```
    TypeAdapterFactory lowercaseKeyTypeAdapterFactory = new TypeAdapterFactory() {
        @Override
        public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
            final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);
            final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type); //
            return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

                public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {

                    if( out instanceof JsonTreeWriter )
                        out.name( out.getName().toLowerCase();

                    JsonElement tree = delegate.toJsonTree(value);
                    elementAdapter.write(out, tree);
                }

                public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                    JsonElement tree = elementAdapter.read(in);
                    return delegate.fromJsonTree(tree);
                }
            };
        }
    };
```