# JAVA - Convert keys JSONObject to lower case

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a problem related to the keys of a JSONObject. I need to change the keys to lowercase, but I'm not getting it, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522853/gson-convert-keys-to-lowercase

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Which package is your `JSONObject` from? If it is from `javax.json` then it is immutable, hence you need to instantiate a new `JSONObject` instance and import modified key value pairs into the new instance (from [JSONObject Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html)).

Comment: my package is from org.json

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).